# Documents and desktop refer to the same folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems

I did a clean install and tried to refer my default folders (videos/documents/desktop/music/downloads) to folders on my D: drive. I guess I accidently selected the same folder for documents and desktop. When I try to change the location of one of them they both refer to the same location, they also take each others name (they are both called desktop or both called documents)

[image]

*bureaublad is dutch for desktop.*

for example I change the location of desktop to d:/desktop the location of documents also changes to d:/desktop.

I rebooted multiple times, I tried to select move files when changing location and also clicked dont move files but nothing helped.

How can I avoid the location change changing both the locations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you can go to the registry and change it manually:

```
HKCU > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > Explorer > User Shell Folders
```

Then logoff or reboot the computer to apply the changes.

Source: https://adamclark.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/setting-my-desktop-location-with-windows-7/

Comment: Thank you this works, any idea on how to change the name? The location is changed succesfull but I still have two folders called desktop. Editing the name under right click properties is disabled.

Comment: open `%userprofile%` and F2 the folder. Don't forget to logoff to apply. (PS I'd be glad if you accepted my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-folders-merged-music-videos-same-folder/
Extremely helpful.check this link.I had the same problem

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.